# How to display posts from two taxonomies?

Tags: taxonomy

I have site with rankings of doctors. Medical specialization and localization where doctors live is stored as a taxonomy.

For example:
`city -> New York, London, Paris`
`specialization -> surgeon, dentist, orthopaedist`

If I want to display all the doctors from London, I have to navigate with my browser to: `http://my_site/city/london`
but where should I navigate when I want to display all dentists from London?

Answer (score 1):

You should move - if not hierarchical - to "post_tags", or a custom non-hierarchical taxonomy.

The rest is more a query Question:

- New template > Query taxonomy > Add specific tags to the query
- Assign template to page
- Add page to menu

So if you link to london and want to display *all* doctors, *including* location **and** specialization, Query for the taxonomy "city" > "london" and add tags "location" and "speziality".

Answer (score 0):

The query should be:

```
www.mysite.com?city=london&specjalization=desntist
```

Comment: if you need advanced rewrite rules to go along with this solution then check out this tutorial: http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/